# Read Committed Snapshot

Tags: sql, sql-server

Once you alter database to use Read Commited Snapshot isolation level, OR snapshot isolation level

Do all transaction now uses that isolation as default or Read Commited is stil the default isolation level and you have to change all stored proc to use by specifying

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Read_committed_snapshot to use Read Committed Snapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire database and code and transaction all use whatever your setting us

Unless you set SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in the code somewhere separately...

Comment: gbn, to clarify default isolation level is still read committed unless you explictly use set transaction isolation level on each of your stored proc or adhoc SQL statement?

In other words for each connection you need to specify read commited snapshot to use that transaction? correct?

Comment: No: all code uses the database level setting. You don't set it individually.

Comment: OK so by issuing ALTER DATABASE <database> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON; you are changing default isolation level from read committed to read committed snapshot?

Comment: Yes: note, it isn't instant as per this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095.aspx I've not used it so can't add any more to the info in this link